# C++ public constructor address 

Tags: c++, constructor

After writing the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef struct Node {
    int value;

    Node(int index) { 
        value = index;
    }
} Node;

int main() {
    Node* arr[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr[i] = &Node(i);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << arr[i]->value << endl;
}
```

I saw that the code prints only 9's instead of all the numbers from 0 to 9 it was supposed to.
After debugging the code i saw that address of arr[i] for each i are the same, and Node(i) have freed the space for arr[i] only once, and after that the only thing it is `value = index` without freeing any other space. Why?

Comment: On codepad: http://codepad.org/boErRgnM it gives a warning about `&Node(i)` being a temporary. Maybe you should just stick with `new Node(i)`

Comment: I just wondered after mistakenly writing this

Comment: The best way to avoid problems is to make sure your code compiles with 0 warnings. A warning is technically valid C but is nearly always a programming error that will lead to a problem. You should **ALWAYS** make sure there are no warnings (and turn your warnings as high as feasible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line: `arr[i] = &Node(i);` is storing a pointer to a temporary object. `Node(i)` creates a temporary object that can be destructed at the end of the statement, at which point all references to it become invalid meaning the results of any code that dereferences `arr[i]` will be undefined. The reason in this case you get all 9's is because the compiler is optimizing the code -- since only 1 temporary `Node(i)` is being created at a time, the compiler is just reusing that memory each time through the loop.

To fix the problem, allocate memory off the heap for each object: `arr[i] = new Node(i);`. Then when you are done using them you will also need to remember to delete each one:

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
    delete arr[i];
}
```

If you want to investigate farther, try adding some code to your `Node` class to see what's happening: for example print out the address of `this` in your constructor, and/or create a destructor that just prints a message out so you can see it being called.

Comment: Why are we dynamically allocating the Node objects? would a better solution be to have an array of Node objects rather than array of Node pointers.

Comment: @Martin For this limited code sample that's a possibility too (and admittedly better for this code sample but then I would suggest just getting rid of the `Node` structure altogether and just print the numbers from 1 to 10), but a `Node` structure like this is usually used in a tree or list structure where `Node`s will be swapped around a lot and swapping the addresses is a lot faster than the actual structures.

Answer (score 5):

To create new objects, use `new Node(i)` otherwise you are creating temporary objects on the stack which is why they are all the same.

Remember to call delete on each object that you get back from new.

Comment: But why are all those temporary objects are with the same address?

Comment: @The GiG Just a coincidence. The compiler happened to make it do that in this case.

Comment: @The GiG, Each object is destroyed right after you take the address. As a result, that space is available for the next object. Hence it ends up reusing the space. You can't depend on that, but that's probably what's happening here.

Comment: @TheGiG because Node leaves scope immediately after executing the statement thus the stack on that address is free again for another instance

Comment: Much simpler to explain how to use objects correctly in this context.

Answer (score 3):

```
&Node(i)
```

This expression creates a temporary variable and returns its address. The temporary is then destroyed, and the next time the expression is evaluated, another temporary is created in the same place — hence the identical addresses.

You should probably eliminate the use of pointers, and introduce a default value for Node.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef struct Node {
    int value;

    Node(int index) { 
        value = index;
    }

    Node() : value( 0 ) {} // allow default construction
} Node;

int main() {
    Node arr[10]; // default-construct array values
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr[i] = Node(i);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << arr[i].value << endl;
}
```

Do not use `new Node` for each object individually. *Always* use a container object to manage a group of objects with similar semantics. You might use `std::vector` here, or `std::array` if you have it. The overhead introduced by `std::vector` will be less than that introduced by `new`.

Comment: +1 Best answer. Given the choice you should be using objects 99% of the time (especially for something as simple as Node).